# How To 'Refresh Data Connection' Tied To Pivot Tables On A Protected Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, database-connection

I have an excel workbook that contains a protected sheet with PivotTables and Pivot Charts.  The source data for the Pivot Tables is a data connection from MS Access on an unprotected sheet. On `Workbook_Open`, I'm trying to un-protect the Chart sheet (which contains the PivotTables & Charts) and then refresh the data connection on the Data sheet (which is already unprotected) and contains the source data. The code I'm using on `WorkBook_Open` does not refresh my data connection.

I've tried several methods to include un-protecting the sheet on `Workbook_BeforeClose` and Open, refreshing on open and close using 
`Sheets("Data").EnableCalculation = True`  and then protecting on open to no avail.

I keep getting this error:

> "Command cannot be performed while a protected sheet contains another PivotTable report based on the same source data".

I have numerous PivotTables pulling data from the DataConnection.  When I used the `EnableCalculation` method nothing happens, but when I try a Refresh, I receive that error. Please see my code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Worksheets("Charts").Activate
  ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

    worksheetactiveprotect
End Sub

Sub worksheetactiveprotect()
 Dim WS As Worksheet
 Dim PF As PivotField
 Dim PT As PivotTable

 On Error Resume Next
 Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Charts")
 On Error GoTo 0
 If WS Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Data sheet not found"
 Else
   If WS.Name = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then

    Sheets("Charts").Unprotect Password:="mypassword"

        Sheets("Charts").EnableCalculation = True
        Sheets("Data").EnableCalculation = True

    Sheets("Charts").Protect Password:="mypassword" _
    , AllowUsingPivotTables:=False, AllowFiltering:=True

    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
  End With
DoEvents
    Sheets("Charts").EnableCalculation = True
    Sheets("Data").EnableCalculation = True
DoEvents
    Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

I expected this code to un-protect the Charts sheet, then refresh the Data sheet (Data Connection) and then Protect the Charts sheet so that users can not manipulate the Charts or PivotTables on the Charts sheet.

Comment: Does refreshing the data itself do the job?  Where is the refresh in your code?

Comment: Nathan, I don't know why this wasn't working before.  I added    Application.Calculate and     ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll and it's working now.  Previously when I used     ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll I received the above error, it appears to be working now.  Thank you!